# How To Get Full File and Folder Structure from Box API In A Single Request

Tags: box-api

Is it possible to get a single JSON response containing the complete file/folder tree for an authenticated user in the Box API? If so, what is the request/endpoint to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it's not currently possible.

Comment: With many accounts having millions of documents they are collaborated on, it usually ends up not being a very wise thing to do.

Comment: Indeed. My implementation, however, limits the number of files/folders so it would never be very large/complex.